# C++: Overloading function by vector size

Tags: c++, function, vector, arguments, size

I have a function which converts a vector to a point like so:

```
Point2D<T> VectorToPoint(std::vector<T> &vec)
{
}

Point3D<T> VectorToPoint(std::vector<T> &vec)
{
}
```

Obviously, this won't compile. I want to overload it so that I can return the correct point type based on the vector size. This is easy with arrays, as shown below. Can I do this with vectors?

```
Point2D<T> ArrayToPoint(T (&arr)[2])
{
}

Point3D<T> ArrayToPoint(T (&arr)[3])
{
}
```

Comment: since the type passed in is the same, unfortunately this is not possible.

Comment: You would need to apply compile time constraints on the overloads but since the vector size is only known at runtime this is not possible. Try using runtime polymorphism (a common base for `Point2D` and `Point3D`) to return the correct runtime type.

Comment: Besides the common base idea, you can look at `boost::variant` or `boost::any`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `std::vector` does not change with its size; therefore, this cannot be done with overloaded methods. In fact, the size of a vector is a runtime property and thus cannot be determined at compile time which is when the types are determined and overload resolution is performed.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with `std::vector`, because a vector is resizable at runtime; however it ought to be possible with `std::array`, which has a fixed size.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Answer (score 2):

I jest, but for those who says it can't be done (tm) -

```
try{
   VectorToPoint( pointVector );
}catch(Point3D point){
   // Deal with this kind of point
}catch(Point2D point){
  // And this other kind of point
}
```

Your function will need to `throw Point2D` or `throw Point3D` based on size of the vector.

This is not a good idea though.

Comment: @StilesCrisis  `catch(StilesDownvote sd){ stilec.postToCommentLog("It is pretty close to what OP is asking for though."); }`